# 36V solar panel with a 12V battery, results in 12 watts a day?

Tags: photovoltaics, solar

So I bought a retired 175W solar panel 36.8V rated voltage, 4.9A rated amps. I hooked it up to a solar charge controller and a 12V battery. Normally the controller doesn't work cos the PV voltage is too high, but if it's connected in the morning before any sunlight, then the voltage is low enough for everything to function, then later in the day, the battery drags down the voltage into acceptable range.

I guess I'm starting to answer my own question, if the PV is only 5 amps, then it's 5 amps at 12V or 60W, or 5 amps at 36V 180W. But anyway the question is,

How and why is it possible that after leaving the system as is for 24 hour intervals, I'm only getting 11 watts of work on the output of the whole thing. On the load section I have a 70 amp relay that connects the inverter to the battery to avoid parasitic drain.

Even if it was changing at 60W, it would be 60W for hours, so I end up having one-twentieth of the power than I should even under the worst conditions, where does it go?

I'd the PV makes no amps, and it's connected, does the battery push current the other direction and discharge itself? Do I need to put a diode or something?

Yeah I'll put more 12V batteries in series, I'm just testing things for fun.

Comment: Notes: "12 watts a day" isn't a proper measurement. "12 watts **for** a day" would make more sense and would equate to an **energy** of 12 W x 24 h = 288 Wh. "*11 watts of work*" isn't right either.  Work would have units of joules (= watt-seconds) or Wh.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. After many different days of having the solar controller connected to the battery and the pv, each day, with a kw meter, I'm only able to get 0.011 kw. So the system is only making 0.011 kw a day, despite it being a 175w panel being hooked up all day.

Comment: Just to clarify again, 'kW' (note capital 'W') is the **power** it is producing at an instant of time. '**kWh**' is the **energy** it produces in a day or some other time period. **Energy = Power x Time**.

Comment: "where does the [power] go? It's not necessarily going anywhere, the controller may not be taking it. Just because your panel has a maximum output of ~5 A doesn't mean the panel produces 5 A just because there's sunshine. The controller needs to actively extract the current, and hence power. If the controller isn't designed to connect a 36 V panel to a 12 V battery then it may not take the available power. If the controller is designed to connect a 36 V panel to a 36 V battery then you need to provide a 36 V battery to get the controller working properly.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the solar panel controller manual or webpage?

Comment: I've done days where I connected the pv to the battery directly without putting the solar controller and the outcome has been the same. With the solar controller it says it's connecting the battery to the pv, and the load is off, then the battery goes up to 12.5v or 12.6v through out the day, then eventually when the sun sets it turns on the load and powers it for 11wh, it didn't turn the load on earlier because it never hit the 12.9v required in the settings to cycle the load on

Comment: How are you determining that you are getting "11 watts of work" or "powers it for 11 wh"?  As Transistor noted, you're confusing power and energy, but if you can explain how you're measuring the 11 whatevers, it may help with answering the question.

Comment: Can you tell us the model number of your solar panel controller? 12.6 V is the voltage you get from a nominal 12 V lead-acid battery that is fully charged but not being charged. Unless your controller is actually specified to charge a 12 V battery from a 36 V panel you can't expect anything useful to happen. You need to give us some information about your solar controller before anyone can give you any useful advice.

Comment: The solar controller is specified to charge 12v n 24v batteries. No it's not speced to charge a 12v battery with a 24v panel. I tried to remove the solar controller variable by telling you I bolted the battery straight to the pv for the same outcome. Well? Why not? Why can't I expect something useful from connecting a 36v pv to a 12v battery? That's the question, explain the physics of that because imo it should work in theory. It's a 12v lead acid car battery. It only reads 12.6 because I'm not getting enough power to charge it fully

Comment: Controllers that work for both 12 and 24 will make an assumption about the configuration based on the voltage at boot; there should be instructions with your controller.  Panels function as RESISTORS and DC sources.  Lead acid batteries are pretty robust compared to lithium, but even so 30+V directly to a 12V may cause issues such as damage to the battery; this is why a charge controller is needed to stop charging after the battery has had enough.  Continuing to charge after will push chemicals beyond design limits and may even cause undesired discharge that may even be sudden and uncontrolled

Comment: can you clarify what the controller is?

Comment: You mean 11 Watt-hours per day?

Comment: @user2656801 there is no reason you shouldn't be able to get something useful from connecting a 36V to a 12V battery as long as the battery does not overcharge. The battery will 'drag' the panel down to its own voltage (unless the panel is very big and the battery is very small) - it's effectively a short-circuit for the panel - so it's not an optimum operating point - and you also have to make sure not to damage the battery by charging it above its maximum voltage - but it definitely does work.

Comment: Do consider testing the battery. Lead-acid batteries do wear out, especially if stored in a discharged state. Fully charge it with a wall charger and test how long it lasts.

Comment: You can also test the current from the solar panel. Probably the actual charge current you get is close to the short circuit current. It is safe to short-circuit the solar panel and measure the current. Note that your multimeter needs a 10-amp measurement range (or more) (some don't) and should be set to that range and probably has a specific plug socket which you have to use for this measurement range.

Comment: An intelligent Solar charger may not fit your description and we still don’t know your model #! It should not pull down the  solar panel more than 30% from no load and ideally down only 18% in full sun or 82% of Voc using DC-DC conversion and preferably with impedance matching or hunting with MPPT control. The battery side charging is separate and draws power from controller by voltage control for the known number of cells eg. 12x2V or 6x2V . A dumb controller ignores MPT conditions on the PV and loses efficiency rapidly with PV voltage and just tries to go CV to battery and fails .

Answer (score 1):

5A rated means someone did some rating math at 5A.

Check the charge controller specs.  It may shut off if the panel voltage is too high ie would result in too much current to battery.

Check panel Open Loop Voltage and make sure it is in spec for charge controller (in the 12V config)

Finally panels also behave like resistors. They will get hot- more if the charge is not flowing to the batteries.  Overheating panels get damaged... and retired.  You may be able to find which cell(s) is/are defective and bypass those.

Stressing the resistor behavior, when you attach panels directly to batteries (and there isn't much sun available), you are putting a resistor across them and draining them (and putting unnecessary wear on already retired panels)!

Comment: A resistor does not dissipate heat with no current flowing and neither does a Solar Panel. It is not like a resistor, it is a voltage-limited current source that peaks around 83% of Voc for Vmpt.

Comment: And how do you propose to stop the unfavorable flow of current in the panel itself at the location where voltage is generated while still allowing the flow you desire?  People have been mucking with the cell composition for years to improve it and the panels we have are the result.  Voltage limited, light dependent energy source with a resistor in parallel.

Comment: The PV generates voltage with some impedance while the load generates current in a loop. With open cct, Voc , there is no current nor heat dissipated. While the solarity is proportional to current, the MPT impedance rises with lower current while the absolute current remains relatively constant when shorted below Vmpt as you expet from a high impedance current source.

Comment: @Tony people like you seem to only believe something they're told by a "reputable" source so 
look at Rsh in the image at https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/modeling-steps/2-dc-module-iv/diode-equivalent-circuit-models/

Comment: It is not just a belief. The shunt resistance does not dissipate any significant heat or draw significant current during Voc. Your answer contradicts this fact.  (-1 for that )

Comment: Open circuit for the cell is incapable of opening Rsh.  It only opens Rs.  Significance is an opinion. Rs 0%, Rsh near 100%.  Energy in sunlight is still the same and it gets turned into heat on the panel. just happens to be high voltage low current, but power =current*voltage

Comment: Yes it is subjective.  Significance is relative to tolerances and variances.  Here insignificant losses means  Rsh power losses are < 5% compared to total worst case., Very insignificant < 0.5%  But faults in cells will increase this will be considered as defects.

Comment: Consider that during MPPT or at Pmpt=Vmpt*Impt that  Vmpt/Imp = Load Z matched impedance and also = Voc/Isc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138375/discussion-between-tony-stewart-ee75-and-abel).

Answer (score 1):

A proper Solar controller will keep the PV voltage high where Maximum Power can be delivered with a matched impedance, while the DCDC converter reduces the voltage to manage the charge voltage with the power available.

Your controller does not appear to do this.  A photo or model with a link can confirm it.

This is the standard PV characteristic at max solarity. With reduced sun power the curves shink in current and power while voltage only drops slightly due to the losses from the series resistance.  For example Vmpt~ 82% Voc at 100% solarity and 72% Voc and 10% solarity while Zmpt rises 9x or so.

Meanwhile, a car battery with very low ESR in tens of milliohms or less with hundreds of Amps would be seen as a short circuit to a PV thus the green load line would be vertical.  A 12V battery on a 36V PV array reduces the maximum power to 1/3 rated power unless a tracking or impedance matching switching DCDC converter is used for MPT tracking to raise/match the PV voltage to Vmpt.

[image]

If however there is no reverse blocking diode added the internal diode characteristics go from being reverse biased supplying current to forward biased and will self-destruct from heat supplied by a battery in darkness.

references
https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maximum_power_point_tracking

Comment: You're assuming its an MPPT controller, PWM is still widely used.

Comment: @GregLocock and some expect it to work without any controller...

Comment: BTDT when debugging a ratty old system

Comment: @GregLocock you are assuming what?  I show “how to control PV” for max efficiency and power transfer using % Voc . Even open loop would work. PWM is what efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but from memory back in the day solar controllers had quite tight max panel voltage limitations, these days now that MPPT for 12/24v are ubiquitous not so much. For instance this is running mine, and the max continuous voltage (100V) is less than  double the max battery voltage (60V for 3 minutes, 48V nominal)

https://www.rpc.com.au/pdf/plasmatronics_PL_reference_manual.pdf

So a nasty cheap old 12V system might struggle with a 36 OCV panel, but you are right, that doesn't affect your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It will charge at 5 amps until the battery reaches float voltage, then the charge controller will turn off. After it turns off, it won't charge any more.

If it stays on all day, charging at 5A for 10 hours, then you've got 5 * 13 * 10 = 650 Watt Hours. If your battery is in good condition, you should be able to get most of that out again.

If you aren't getting ~500 Watt Hour (~400 Amp Hour) into your load (12W for 50 hours, or 2.5A for 20 hour or whatever), then either you aren't getting 5A for 10 hours, or your load measurement is wrong, or your battery has failed.

(The panel will run coolest when operating at Maximum Power Point: short circuit or open circuit it will run warmer. Warmer or colder, the 12-14V current will mostly depend on the sunlight, and for the same sun will be slightly greater than the specified operating current.)